# Why does libc++'s implementation of map use this union?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, stl, libc++

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L

template <class _Key, class _Tp>
union __value_type
{
    typedef _Key                                     key_type;
    typedef _Tp                                      mapped_type;
    typedef pair<const key_type, mapped_type>        value_type;
    typedef pair<key_type, mapped_type>              __nc_value_type;

    value_type __cc;
    __nc_value_type __nc;

    template <class ..._Args>
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    __value_type(_Args&& ...__args)
        : __cc(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...) {}

    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    __value_type(const __value_type& __v)
        : __cc(__v.__cc) {}

    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    __value_type(__value_type& __v)
        : __cc(__v.__cc) {}

    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    __value_type(__value_type&& __v)
        : __nc(std::move(__v.__nc)) {}

    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    __value_type& operator=(const __value_type& __v)
        {__nc = __v.__cc; return *this;}

    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    __value_type& operator=(__value_type&& __v)
        {__nc = std::move(__v.__nc); return *this;}

    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    ~__value_type() {__cc.~value_type();}
};

#else
// definition for C++03...
```

It looks like the purpose is to make `__value_type` assignable and movable while also being able to expose the content as `pair<const key_type, mapped_type>` (which is the value type of iterators and so on). But I don't see why it needs to be assignable or movable, since I can't see any reason why the implementation would ever need to copy or move nodes inside a map, or indeed to do anything other than construct and destroy them in-place, and reconfigure pointers.

Comment: Did you try searching the file for uses of `__nc`? Note, either way, the usage suggested by this union is not conforming.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Yes, it's only used to implement the members shown.

Comment: This might be a defect in the core language, the library, or both. Usually the library is supposed to be implementable using the language. Do you want to report the issue(s)?

Comment: @Potatoswatter implementations are allowed to use "magic"

Comment: @MattMcNabb The magic parts of the standard library are mostly kept to §18. The intent of the committee is that magic not be required for ordinary sorts of data structures. Likewise, libc++ is a different project from Clang, and many other standard libraries are intended to be portable to at least some degree.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use a custom allocator, it may be necessary to move the map (and its contents) into a new resource pool. In that case, this overload will provide movable access to the keys:

```
__value_type(__value_type&& __v)
    : __nc(std::move(__v.__nc)) {}
```

It doesn't matter that keys have been moved-from, since the next thing that happens is freeing all the nodes.

Note, this usage may incur undefined behavior. You can't generally write one member of a union and then read another. Clang and libc++ can do this as long as they can internally guarantee it won't cause a problem (or error diagnosis).

They probably did it this way, though, because there is no good conforming alternative. At least, I can't think of one. The standard requires that `value_type::first_type` is genuinely `const` qualified, so even a `const_cast` is not allowed.

The trick is conforming in the case that `key_type` and `mapped_type` are both standard layout, so that `std::pair<key_type, mapped_type>` and `std::pair<key_type const, mapped_type>` are layout-compatible, per [class.mem] §9.2/16. It looks a bit odd here because the function is referring to the immediate members `__cc` and `__nc` of the union, leaving it to the constructor to access the common subsequence comprising `first` and `second`. The [requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/StandardLayoutType) for standard-layout types are somewhat restrictive, but many common key and value types (for example, `std::string`) can potentially meet them.

Comment: This is not conforming. 9.2/16 applies only to standard-layout structs, and `K` and `V` are not necessarily standard-layout. Moreover, you are only allowed to read the common initial sequence, but moving typically requires a write.

Comment: @T.C. - On the other hand, a standard library implementation is allowed to use constructs that its compiler has made well-defined (as an extension, possibly undocumented).

Comment: @T.C. Thanks, I restored the original paragraph and revised. The language I see regarding reading and writing is "permitted to inspect," which is clear as mud.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks, I looked for something like that but didn't find it. That DR mentions "specific use-cases involving std::pair and the like," which makes it seem tailored to just this implementation issue. It would be odd if it didn't go far enough to actually support it. Though, I suppose, the weirdness of `std::map` keys causes problems for other folks too.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I was referring to item 4 in the resolution, which clarifies that "inspect" means "read". Regardless, the key was constructed as `const`, and there's a blanket rule that says attempting to modify a `const` object is UB.

Comment: The union trick doesn't work if users specialize `std::pair<X,Y>` such that its layout changes (e.g. by adding padding or increasing alignment of one member) but don't also specialize `std::pair<const X, Y>` ([example that would crash with libc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/552a3e0c890d72f1)). Howard and I have discussed this and I want to ban such specializations, so that standard libraries are allowed to perform these kind of optimisations. Currently I think it's not allowed, but only fails if users do crazy things, and I don't like crazy users.

Comment: The union trick also writes to the `__nc` member, making it the active member, then reads from `__cc` which is not the active member. That is UB unless the compiler makes type-punning well-defined (which is true of GCC and Clang, so it's OK for libc++, if you ignore alignment and constness issues).

Answer (score 11):

This is in support of [Potatoswatter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153285/potatoswatter)'s answer.  I answer as the author of this libc++ code.

Consider:

```
int
main()
{
    std::map<A, int> m1;
    m1[A{1}] = 1;
    m1[A{2}] = 2;
    m1[A{3}] = 3;
    std::map<A, int> m2;
    m2[A{4}] = 4;
    m2[A{5}] = 5;
    m2[A{6}] = 6;
    std::cout << "start copy assignment\n";
    m2 = m1;
    std::cout << "end copy assignment\n";
}
```

In this particular circumstance I foresaw the need to both recycle nodes of the map, and reassign the "const" keys to make the recycling of nodes efficient.  Therefore

http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#704

inserted the following wording to allow for recycling of `map` nodes:

> The associative containers meet all of the requirements of
>   Allocator-aware containers (23.2.1 [container.requirements.general]),
>   except for the containers map and multimap, the requirements placed on
>   value_type in Table 93 apply instead directly to key_type and
>   mapped_type. [Note: For example key_type and mapped_type are sometimes
>   required to be CopyAssignable even though the value_type (pair) is not CopyAssignable. — end note]

Thus allowing the containers non-const access to the map's key_type.  To date, only libc++ takes advantage of this.  If you instrument `A` in the above example you will get for libc++:

```
start copy assignment
operator=(const A& a)
operator=(const A& a)
operator=(const A& a)
end copy assignment
```

For libstdc++ (gcc-5.2.0)

```
start copy assignment
~A()
A(A const& a)
~A()
A(A const& a)
~A()
A(A const& a)
end copy assignment
```

For VS-2015:

```
start copy assignment
~A()
~A()
~A()
A(A const& a)
A(A const& a)
A(A const& a)
end copy assignment
```

I assert that when `A` is a type such as `int`, `std::vector` or `std::string`, or a type containing one of these common std types, there is a tremendous performance advantage of assignment over destruction followed by construction.  Assignment can take advantage of existing capacity in the lhs, often resulting in a simple `memcpy` as opposed to a deallocation of memory followed by an allocation of memory.

Note that above `~A()` likely implies deallocation of the entire node, not just `A` (though not necessarily).  In any event, the libc++ `map` copy assignment operator is highly optimized to recycle memory, and permission for that optimization is backed by the C++11 and beyond standards.  The union trick is one (not necessarily portable) way of achieving that optimization.

A similar optimization is obtained by this same code for the move assignment operator when the allocator does not propagate on move assignment and the two allocators compare unequal:

clang/libc++:

```
start move assignment
operator=(A&& a)
operator=(A&& a)
operator=(A&& a)
end move assignment
```

gcc-5.2.0

```
start move assignment
~A()
A(A const& a)
~A()
A(A const& a)
~A()
A(A const& a)
~A()
~A()
~A()
end move assignment
```

VS-2015

```
start move assignment
~A()
~A()
~A()
A(A const& a)
A(A const& a)
A(A const& a)
end move assignment
```

Comment: _"Note that above `~A()` likely implies deallocation of the entire node, not just `A`"_ Not for libstdc++. We recycle the memory for nodes on assignment, but we destroy the old object at that location and construct a new one, so we avoid one level of re-allocation (but if `A` allocates its own memory we still deallocate all that and reallocate when constructing a new `A`).